# determinant of the Fubini-Study metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, determinant, kahler-manifolds

Is there any easy way to compute the determinant of the Fubini-Study metric, given by:

$g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}=\frac{1}{1+\bar{z}z}\left(\delta_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}-\frac{\bar{z}_\alpha z_{\bar{\beta}}}{1+\bar{z}z}\right)$ ?

I've tried using the relation of the determinant and the Levi-Civita connections $\Gamma^\gamma_{\bar{\beta}\gamma}$ (since my goal at the end would be to compute the Ricci curvature tensor $R_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}$). The Ricci curvature tensor is given by:

$R_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}=-\partial_\alpha\partial_{\bar{\beta}}\left(\log(\det g_{\gamma\bar{\delta}})\right)=-\partial_\alpha\left(g^{\gamma\bar{\delta}}\partial_\bar{\beta}g_{\gamma\bar{\delta}}\right).$

Where I got the last equality by using the Levi-Civita connection do solve the determinant. Now I'm still having problems with the calculations of the last term, any hints on that one ?

Any help would be most welcome!

A solution to the determinant would be most helpfull since I think I could compare this with the Kähler-potential given by $K(z,\bar{z})=\log(1+z\bar{z})$, for which we have that $g_{\alpha\bar{\beta}}=\partial_\alpha\partial_{\bar{\beta}}K(z,\bar{z})$.

> Edit, since I've seen people asking this question before. I'm working on a complex manifold with coordinates $z^a=\{z^\alpha,\bar{z}^\bar{\alpha}\}$, where $a=1,...,2n$ and $\alpha=1,...,n$. So when I write Greek indices, I've split up the 2n linear independent (denoted by an $a$) into two groups, the holomorphic (denoted by $\alpha$) and anti-holomorphic (denoted by $\bar{\alpha}$) coordinates.

Comment: I'm not sure it gets much easier than in the answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426994/positive-definiteness-of-fubini-study-metric

You could also calculate the determinant as a corollary of the matrix determinant lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) since the matrix we have is is $a I + a^2 \, {}^t \bar z z$ for a suitable $a$.

Comment: Thanks, that at least gives me a place to start ! :)